# Boot camp assistant: Size of winddows support software download

Tags: bootcamp

My boot camp assistant has been downloading "windows support software" for a long time. There is no speed indicator, or total download size.

I have tracked the network activity in activity monitor and it has so far downloaded 2.5GB and counting.

Does anyone have any idea how big this download is? It is unbelievable for them to have such a huge download without an estimate of time remaining or progress... what an absolute joke.

Update: The mac is a mac mini late 2012 running yosemite, trying to install Windows 8.1 retail.

The eventual download size was 2.8GB.

Comment: This depends on the model of your Mac and the version of Windows you are installing. For older versions of Windows, there are alternate Apple download sites. Could you update your question to include this information?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that something else must be wrong because the Bootcamp Support Software should be less than 1GB if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As for March 4th 2020, mine was 4.5GB (MacBook Pro 2015)[image]